# SQL Server 2012 Always on and .net app

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2012, high-availability

Is there any restriction to connect .net (2.0 and 4.0) application to SQL Server 2012 AAG ?

Do I have something special on DB connection string? Is this technology fully transparent to the programmer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be this is the answer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2654347 but i am not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do something special in the connection string to take full advantage of AAGs. There are two new properties that support connections to an AAG group listener: ApplicationIntent can be used to connect to a readable secondary for read-only workloads, and MultiSubnetFailover optimizes connection retries during failover. You still need to do connection retries in the application but using MultiSubnetFailover=True will minimize the retries. These new properties are only supported in .NET 4.0 or higher. Here's MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205662(v=vs.100).aspx

Other than connection handling and distinguishing read-only and read-write workloads, it is transparent to the application.